# Showing error with icon and custom message in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html, css, error-handling, frontend

Recently I came across a website which had pretty neat way for displaying the error, I was thinking to implement same on my website but couldn't figure out the the way to make it happen via Angularjs.

[image]

The error show up as soon as I go the next field.

Comment: the image is not showing, are you mean validations in angular js ?

Comment: please check these links:

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_validation.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the red box on the fields, you can use `ng-invalid`and `ng-touched` class and build a specific css rule for both of them.

`ng-invalid` indicates that the field is not well filled.
`ng-touched` indicates that the field has been touched by the user.

**css class example**

```js
const myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

```css
.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<form>
<input type="text" required name="input1" ng-model="model1">
<input type="text" required name="input2" ng-model="model1">
</form>
</body>
```

For a clean result including the feedback icon (!), you can check [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) combined with a ngClass using `myForm.myInputName.$invalid && myForm.myInputName.$dirty`

For the message, you must use the input from the formController like explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) and add one message per possible error with a popover lib.

**Full example with bootstrap** :

```js
const myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

```css
.error-message {
  display: block !important;
  margin-top: 30px !important;
  margin-left: -28px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <form name="myForm" class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback " ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.input2.$invalid && myForm.input1.$touched}">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Required input</label>
      <input class="form-control" required type="text" required name="input1" ng-model="model1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="popover bottom error-message" ng-if="myForm.input1.$error.required && myForm.input1.$touched"> 
  <div class="arrow"></div> 
  <h3 class="popover-title">Required</h3> 
  </div>
  </span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-feedback" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm.input2.$invalid && myForm.input2.$touched}">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputError2">Required input</label>
      <input class="form-control" required type="text" required name="input2" ng-model="model1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="popover bottom error-message" ng-if="myForm.input2.$error.required && myForm.input2.$touched"> 
  <div class="arrow"></div> 
  <h3 class="popover-title">Required</h3> 
  </div>
  </span>
    </div>


  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This works for me had to change little bit accordingly, though I have 1 more question how do I suppress the default HTML5 message which pops up when I click submit.

Comment: add [novalidate attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_form_novalidate.asp) on your form. It will desactivate html5 validation.